# Why is the set of Hermitian matrices with repeated eigenvalue of measure zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, sp.spectral-theory, random-matrices, eigenvalues

The Hermitian matrices form a real vector space where we have a Lebesgue measure. In the set of Hermitian matrices with Lebesgue measure, how does it follow that the set of Hermitian matrices with repeated eigenvalue is of measure zero?

This result feels extremely natural but I do not see an immediate argument for it.

Comment: The existence of a repeated eigenvalue is equivalent to the vanishing of the resultant of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg, [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420319/matrices-with-repeated-eigenvalue-are-of-measure-zero#comment1079538_420319) shows that we have a Zariski-closed, proper subset, but is it obvious (as opposed to intuitive!) that that forces the Haar measure to be $0$?

Comment: It occurs to me after my earlier [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420319/matrices-with-repeated-eigenvalue-are-of-measure-zero#comment1079539_420319) that I don't even understand the question.  Haar measure is defined on a group, but the Hermitian matrices of a fixed size (greater than $1$) do not form a group.  What is the ambient group whose Haar measure you are using?

Comment: @LSpice I tried to clarify the meaning of Haar measure and called it Lebesgue measure. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Ah, I see.  I was looking for a multiplicative structure.  The Hermitian matrices of fixed size form a real vector space, not a complex one, but otherwise, yes, it now makes sense.

Comment: @LSpice Here's a silly approach. Since it's closed, it's measurable. If it doesn't have measure 0, its intersection with some hypercube, say $[0,1]^n$, has positive measure $p$. Then if we sample for each $i$ from $1$ to $n$ a total of $m$ i.i.d coordinates uniformly from $[0,1]$, forming $m^n$ random points, each uniformly  distributed in $[0,1]^n$, so at least $pm^n$ lie in our set. But if the set is defined by an equation of degree $d$, at most $d m^{n-1}$ can, by a standard inductive argument. For $m> d/p$, this gives a contradiction.

Comment: There is a formula for the distribution of eigenvalues of a random Hermitian matrix where the entries are from the standard Gaussian distribution and the probability of getting a repeated eigenvalue is zero with respect to this distribution. Since this Gaussian measure and the Haar measure are mutually absolutely continuous, we know that the set of Hermitian matrices with repeated eigenvalues has measure zero.

Comment: @WillSawin, [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420319/matrices-with-repeated-eigenvalue-are-of-measure-zero/420322#comment1079560_420319) is a cute argument, and not so silly; in fact, I think that Terry Tao's measure-theory notes define Haar measure on Euclidean spaces in this way.  My initial confusion [1](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1079539) and [2](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1079550) was because I wrongly thought we were working in a multiplicative group.

Comment: @LSpice Well, one can compare Haar measure on Euclidean space to an arbitrary group by using Bruhat decomposition to find an open subset and using a change of integration formula... (Maybe one should say the claim that is "obvious' is that a Zariski-closed set not containing any connected component has Haar measure zero.)

Comment: See http://www.math.caltech.edu/SimonPapers/79.pdf, THEOREM 2.1 .

Comment: @jjcale That link provides the best answer to this question, when combined with a standard theorem in differential topology that subvarieties of positive codimension have zero Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @WillSawin: Could you elaborate more on this? "But if the set is defined by an equation of degree $d$, at most $d m^{n−1}$ (points) can (lie in the set), by a standard inductive argument"

Comment: @SiXUlm This is the celebrated https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz%E2%80%93Zippel_lemma

Comment: @WillSawin thank you for the reference. And regarding "But if the set is defined by an equation of degree $d$", do you mean the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: @SiXUlm I mean the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call $S$ the set of matrices with repeated eigenvalues and fix a hermitian matrix $A\not\in S$. In the vector space of hermitian matrices, any line through $A$ intersects $S$ in at most finitely many points. From this it easily follows that $S$ is negligible (using polar coordinates centered at $A$).

To check the claim, note that a line through $A$ consists of matrices of the form $M(t)=(1-t)A+tB$, for some $B\in S$. Hence, the characteristic polynomial of $M(t)$ has the form $\lambda^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}p_k(t)\lambda^k$ for some polynomials $p_k(t)$.

There is a polynomial expression of the coefficients $a_k$ of a polynomial $\lambda^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k\lambda^k$ which vanishes precisely when it has repeated roots: indeed, calling $\alpha_i$ the roots, you can consider the expression $\prod_{i<j}(\alpha_i-\alpha_j)^2$. Since it's symmetric, it is in fact equal to some $P(a_0,\dots,a_{n-1})$. For our matrices, this means that $M(t)\in S$ precisely when $P(p_0(t),\dots,p_{n-1}(t))=0$. The left-hand side is a polynomial, which is not trivial since it does not vanish at $t=0$. Hence, $M(t)\in S$ only for finitely many $t$.

Comment: shaky argument, but yes ;)

Comment: I guess your symmetric matrix is real, so as also to be Hermitian; but I am confused by "any complex line through $A$".  The space of Hermitian matrices is naturally a *real*, but not a complex, vector space; how do you define a complex line?

Comment: @LSpice good points; I corrected my answer.

Comment: (+1) Good and simple argument. To make it unshaky, I expect that (a) you write $\setminus \{\}$ as the cartesian product of a sphere centered at $A$ and the open half line and (b) you use Fubini formula to conclude.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a (I think) mathematically correct, but clearly morally wrong, answer *via* extreme overkill.

Upon multiplying by $i$, we may work instead with skew-Hermitian matrices, i.e., with $\mathfrak u(n)$.  The usual proof of the [Weyl integration formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_integration_formula) on $U(n)$ works just as well for $\mathfrak u(n)$, and gives that
$$
\tag{W}\label{W}
\int_{\mathfrak u(n)} f(X)\mathrm dX = \int_{\mathfrak t} f(Y)\lvert D(Y)\rvert^{1/2}\mathrm dY
$$
for all continuous, compactly supported, $U(n)$-fixed functions $f$ on $\mathfrak u(n)$, where $\mathfrak t$ is the subspace of diagonal matrices in $\mathfrak u(n)$ and $D(Y) = \prod_{\alpha \in \Phi(\mathfrak u(n), \mathfrak t)} \alpha(Y)$ equals the product of pairs of differences of eigenvalues of $Y$.  In particular, the singular set $S$ is the $0$ set of $D$, hence, as @StevenLandsburg [suggested](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420319/matrices-with-repeated-eigenvalue-are-of-measure-zero#comment1079538_420319), is closed.

Now I'll use dominated convergence freely.  To show that $S$ has measure $0$, it suffices to show that its intersection with every compact subset $K$ of $\mathfrak u(n)$ has measure $0$.  Upon replacing such a set $K$ by its $U(n)$-orbit, we may, and do, assume that $K$ is $U(n)$-stable.
Now there is a sequence $(f_k)_{k = 1}^\infty$ of continuous, compactly supported functions, all pointwise between $0$ and $1$, such that $f_k$ tends pointwise to the indicator function of $S \cap K$.
Since $S$, hence $S \cap K$, is stable under $U(n)$-conjugacy, upon replacing each $f_k$ by the average of its $U(n)$-orbits, we may, and do, assume that the sequence consists of continuous class functions.  Then, upon applying \eqref{W} to each such function and taking the limit, we see that
$$
\operatorname{meas}(S \cap K) = \int_{S \cap K} \mathrm dX = \int_{\mathfrak t \cap S \cap K} \lvert D(Y)\rvert^{1/2}\mathrm dY = 0.
$$

Comment: @GuidoLi, you really shouldn't accept this answer, which is just a lark that occurred to me as my first impulse.  I think it is correct, but it is clearly the wrong way to think about it.

Comment: Hilarious! :) ....

Answer (score 6):

Here is another argument.

The idea is that in any neighbourhood of a matrix with repeated roots, there is one with distinct roots.  i.e. we are arguing that matrices with repeated roots are residual, that the matrices with distinct roots are open and dense in the space of matrices.

The idea is to put the matrix into its Jordan form.   Then you can take a small perturbation that makes all the diagonal entries distinct (only perturbing the diagonal entries).   In this form, you can compute the characteristic polynomial and you see the roots are all distinct (as they are the diagonal entries).

I suppose this is essentially Mizar's argument but in a coordinate system where there is a little less work to do.

Comment: This does not answer the question, since it proves only that the inetrior of the set of Hermitian matrices with repeated eigenvalues is void.

Comment: @DenisSerre:  Well, the argument gives a little more than what was stated. The Jordan forms gives a stratification of the space of matrices, with matrices having repeated roots being of positive codimension.   The stratification can be written in the language of Grassman manifolds and associated flag manifolds.  I ?imagine? someone has described this but I don't know this end of the literature very well.